# How to setup a BorderContainer with two regions?

Tags: html, css, dojo, dijit.layout

I have the following layout, I need to adjust the size of "Center pane" to fulfill the screen (100%).
With the following code I am not able to achieve the result.
What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/m8112z2b/

```
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="xxx-dijit-layout-app">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane data-dojo-props=" region:'top'" id="xxx-dijit-layout-control">Top pane</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" id="xxx-dijit-layout-workspace">Center pane</div>
    </div>

        #xxx-dijit-layout-app {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #xxx-dijit-layout-control {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #xxx-dijit-layout-workspace {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your HTML only takes up the height it needs. If you want to make your `<html>` and `<body>` to be 100% high by default, then you have to use:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you do that, then the center pane will take up the entire screen. This will lead to a screen that is 100% + the additional 100px of the top pane. If you want to make it so that the center pane takes the rest of the height, then you should use:

```
#xxx-dijit-layout-workspace {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/at38eh7g/

Answer (score 1):

just add this in your css

```
html,body{

 height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

you have not given any height for your body and html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```